# Return first non null value in each column

Tags: sql, null

I am looking to create a summary/rollup by day and customer ID from a table (table is updating from multiple sources currently).

For each customer ID and transaction date, I'm either looking to get a min, max, sum or first non null value in that column for that combination.  I have no problem with min, max and sum, but am looking for suggestions on how to best handle the first non null value in a column.

Sample of what my table looks like:

```
Cust ID  Trans Date   Housing    Housing $    Retail    Retail $   Arrival
123      1/1/2019     test1      $500.00      NULL      NULL       1/1/2019
123      1/1/2019     NULL       NULL         product1  $15.00     NULL
1235     5/10/2019    test2      $1,000.00    NULL      NULL       5/10/2019
1234     10/15/2019   test2      $1,000.00    NULL      NULL       10/15/2019    
1234     10/15/2019   NULL       NULL         product2  $25.00     NULL
```

Results I'm looking for:

```
123      1/1/2019     test1      $500.00      product1  $15.00     1/1/2019
1235     5/10/2019    test2      $1,000.00    NULL      NULL       5/10/2019
1234     10/15/2019   test2      $1,000.00    product2  $25.00     10/15/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first value" in a column -- `NULL` or otherwise -- unless a column specifies the ordering.

However, for your result set, simple aggregation seems sufficient:

```
select CustID, TransDate, max(Housing), max(Housing$), max(Retail), max(Retail$), max(Arrival)
from t
group by CustID, TransDate;
```